# Tesseract OCR fails to load language

Tags: c++, ocr, tesseract

I'm trying to integrate Tesseract OCR with my xHarobur + Borland C++ app.  In my test Win7 machine everything works fine but when I move everything to the target machine -also Win7- the app fails to load the language module (eng.Traineddata).

In short, TessBaseAPIInit3( handle, NULL, "eng" ) always returns 0 on the target machine while it works just perfectly on my dev machine.  The code up to that line looks like this:

```
...
handle := TessBaseAPICreate()
IF TessBaseAPIInit3( handle, NIL, "eng" ) != 0
   logfile( "trace.log", {"Tesseract fails to load language module", handle }) 
...
```

The log file does shows a valid value for handle as expected.  Therefore we can safely assume TessBaseAPICreate() is returning a valid handle.

In an effort to debug the problem I installed the Tesseract.exe setup program on the target machine and was able to run Tesseract.exe command line obtaining successful results.

I'm told by the IT people that the entire directory where my app is installed which is also where eng.traineddata resides is whitelisted.

Any ideas how to debug this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I think it will be good ideas to list all the language modules supported on the target machine.

Comment: Ritesh- that is a good idea.  How do you get all language modules supported?  Is there an api function to do this?

Comment: @reinaldo Hi don't know of exact api. But its a general practice from library writers to expose apis like these. I think if your try to find in the public api set, you should be able to find.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the problem.  It seems like the app needs to execute with higher user permissions in order to be able to load the language module.  So far I've been able to execute as expected as long as it is executed as administrator.